# How to Show the Colored status or check icon based on column status (yes/no)

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, csom, 2016

I have Custom List for Visitors and I created some custom columns:

- Visitor Name
- Enter Time
- Check Out Time
- Check Out Status etc..

Here I want when Status column value changes to Yes (this type is Yes/No).

I want to display Checked Icon or Green Color in List All items views after user edit the list.

Comment: you want to show checked icon or green color on new/edit/display form or in list views?

Comment: please i will try both first i want to sow Green color in allitems view  after user edit the list item